# VS Code Vim extension

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, extension

So I am trying out the Vim extension for VS Code. All works well, except if doing tab completion for open a new file.  For example, say I my files in the following directory:

```
dir1/dir2/file1.cpp
```

In vim, I can type:

```
:dir1/dir2/file1.cpp
```

Tab key will autocomplete the path as well as the file name.

In VS Code, this does not work. In fact, if I try to press Tab after typing colon, VS Code will insert a Tab character in my source code.

Does anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem detailed in
[Tab completion falls back to inserting tab-character #65587](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65587).

A proposed workaround was:

> I just changed "editor.tabCompletion": "on", to "editor.tabCompletion": "off", and the problem has gone away. Thanks for that hint.

A developer named jrieken has remarked on Jan 22, 2019, that
he has created
[a fix](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e83c7a08a9340f817f708aed0e773d755a7a52f6)
for the problem, which might not have yet made it to the release.